# Custom package's class won't auto-load with composer autoloader

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to publish a new package on Packagist.org but I'm having some troubles using the autoloader system.

While I'm installing my package (https://packagist.org/packages/gabyfle/gsteam-auth) everything is okay, but when I'm loading it throught PHP :

```php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$testing = new \Class\SteamAuth('test', 'test');
```

I got an error, telling me that Class namespace cannot be find.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Class\SteamAuth' not found in <path>\gSteam-test\testing.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in <path>\gSteam-test\testing.php on line 4
```

I already tried every different autoload conventions (PSR0 **and** PSR4), I also tried to include my class in the autoloader throught the `classmap` parameter, but my class isn't loading.

Do you have any idea on how I can make my class being loaded throught the composer's autoloader ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use PSR-4 autoloading. Keep in mind that you have to put trailing backslashes at the end of the namespace declaration:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Gabyfle\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Quote from the composer docs:

> Note that as opposed to the older PSR-0 style, the prefix (Foo\\) is not present in the file path.

And also:

> Namespace prefixes must end in \ to avoid conflicts between similar prefixes. For example Foo would match classes in the FooBar namespace so the trailing backslashes solve the problem: Foo\ and FooBar\ are distinct.

So keep that in mind if you switch from psr-0 to psr-4

Comment: I switched to ``psr-4``, but there is still this error... The class isn't loaded at all.

Comment: Are you testing it locally or installing it through composer install? If the former did you run `composer dump-autoload` to update the composer changes?

Comment: I'm testing it locally. I ran `composer dump-autoload`and it says my that 2 classes were loaded. But that's strange since I got 3 classes in total : 2 for my own lib, and 1 for a dependency

Comment: Could you post your files/folder structure? As I downloaded your package from Github, edited the composer.json with what I put in my answer, ran `composer dump-autoload` and everything worked. So I cannot reproduce the error. Maybe you could also upload the whole testing folder to github in its own test repository

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mdexp, I found what's wrong with my class.
I was defining two classes in one file, and that's not matching with the PSR-4 norme.

I just deleted one class from the file, and everything is now working fine.

Thanks !